# Print two Arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having problems printing these arrays. I get this error:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '+'.
```

Not sure what am I missing. When I print only the first one it works fine but when I add the second doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class testMenu {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] rieslingArray = {"Riesling","Dry","Off Dry", "Sweet"};
double[] rieslingPrice = {3.0,4.50,4.00,5.00};

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rieslingArray  + rieslingPrice);
}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Add 2 arryas?

Comment: What do you expect? Something like `Riesling Dry 3.0, Dry 4.50....` or `Riesling Dry, Dry... 3.0, 4.50....`?

Comment: You're trying to print 2 arrays' items?

Comment: I just want to print both arrays right next to each other like riesling  3.0, Dry 4.50. The name first and next to it the price

Comment: You can see the compilation error ...Its very clear from that....The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String[], double[]

Comment: '+' cannot be applied to arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You're making use of the binary `+` operator. Specifically, you're giving it two arguments of type `String[]` and `double[]` respectively. These types are not valid for the `+` operator.

You can try printing the second array with a second statement or concatenating the string representations of the two arrays and printing that string in a single statement. The following may be useful in getting the string representation of the arrays: `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: I did this: String summary = " Wine"+ rieslingArray + "Price" +rieslingPrice;
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, summary);
but I get random characters on the output

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
String[] rieslingArray = {"Riesling","Dry","Off Dry", "Sweet"};
double[] rieslingPrice = {3.0,4.50,4.00,5.00};

for (int i = 0; i < rieslingArray.length; i++) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rieslingArray[i]  + rieslingPrice[i]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. With this prints the items one by one. Im trying to print all of them at the same time.

Comment: Have a look at `Parker Hoyes` answer!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your confusion here is that you want to map the arrays together element-for-element. Since you're just trying to make a message display on screen, iterating through each array and getting each corresponding element works just fine.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] rieslingArray = {"Riesling", "Dry", "Off Dry", "Sweet"};
        double[] rieslingPrice = {3.0, 4.50, 4.00, 5.00};

        StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < rieslingArray.length; i++) {
            messageBuilder.append(rieslingArray[i] + ": " + rieslingPrice[i] + "\n");
        }
        String message = messageBuilder.toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

    }
}
```